# How do i write a log of .CMD file to text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have a sample.cmd file with some commands , I want to write log of that command file to a text file?

Comment: `command>log.txt` redirects stdout to log.txt.

Comment: @Regejok i have a command file not a single command. So I want that the log of total commands to be captured in a text file.

Comment: same thing, except when you're doing it inside another script. Use `call script` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
>"theFile.log" (
 command1
 command2
 ...
)
```

As inside a block, any output is redirected to `theFile.log`. More over, the file is opened and closed only once.

As all output is sent to `theFile.log`, if you want to display some info on the screen, then redirect it to console `>CON`

```
>"theFile.log" (
 command1
 command2
 command3>CON & rem this is echoed in screen 
 ...
)
```

Any time you use `>` file is created. If you want `append mode` change `>"theFile.log" (` to `>>"theFile.log" (`

EDIT, for your comment

Don't understand your logic...

```
ECHO ON 
REM STEP 1- CHECK FILE 
IF EXIST C:\SAMPLE.TXT (DEL C:\SAMPLE.TXT) 
findstr /I /B .START C:\SAMPLE.TXT > C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT 
EXIT 16
```

You are running `findstr` on a file just deleted.

If you want to check if test if `.START` is present or not

```
@echo off
rem STEP 1- CHECK FILE 
rem Think this line must be 
IF EXIST C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT DEL C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT 

findstr /I /B .START C:\SAMPLE.TXT > C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT && (
  start C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT
) || (
  echo Not found
)  
rem EXIT 16 
exit/B
```

This uses the conditional operators `&&` (previous command successful) and `||` (previous command failed).

Comment: i have a file Test.cmd as below  ECHO ON
REM STEP 1- CHECK FILE

IF EXIST C:\SAMPLE.TXT (DEL C:\SAMPLE.TXT)
findstr /I /B .START C:\SAMPLE.TXT > C:\SAMPLE_START.TXT

EXIT 16  i want to write the log of this Test.cmd file to Test.log  I'm trying like cmd.exe Test.cmd>Test.log  but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... just need to run the file as below on command prompt

C:\user\username>"Test.cmd">"test.log"

Thanks for your suggestions...

Comment: Ok, but see edited answer. It may help